# Creating Javascript RegEx to validate hyphenated BEM and camelCase

Tags: javascript, regex, camelcasing, bem, css-hyphens

I have this Regex for detecting hyphenatedBEM in CSS files

```
^([\.\%]?[a-z]*[-]?[a-z0-9\-]*)(\.[a-z0-9\-]*)?(__[a-z0-9]*[-]?[a-z0-9\-]*)?(--[a-z0-9]*[-]?[a-z0-9\-]*)?(\:[a-z]*)*$
```

but I would also like it to detect CamelCase as well...

I need to do this because we are transitioning from hyphenatedBEM to camelCase

In short, how do I write a regex that checks for

```
^([\.\%]?[a-z]*[-]?[a-z0-9\-]*)(\.[a-z0-9\-]*)?(__[a-z0-9]*[-]?[a-z0-9\-]*)?(--[a-z0-9]*[-]?[a-z0-9\-]*)?(\:[a-z]*)*$

or

\.[a-z][a-z0-9]*[A-Z][a-z0-9]*[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*[a-z][A-Za-z0-9]*
```

If neither validate then it errors/returns false

I would be validating against CSS like below and both should validate as fine...

```
.error__404 { ...SOME CSS CODE... }   --> this is correct
.error__404--red { ...SOME CSS CODE... }   --> this is correct
.userImage { ...SOME CSS CODE...}   --> this is correct
.this-is-not-correct { ...SOME CSS CODE...}   --> this is not correct
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: im no expert in regex, but can't you just combine both regexes in a `[]`?

Comment: Input and expected output...?

Comment: input would be a SCSS file containing **.block__element--modifier** and another SCSS file containing **.camelCase** and BOTH files validating

Comment: I tried to combine in square brackets, but I get Invalid regular expression: Unmatched ')'... Which is odd as all the brackets match up :/

Comment: @Takuhii can you add some example strings to be matched and some others not to be matched?

Comment: The two strings I want to use are above. But I would validate against this;

`.error__404 { ...SOME CSS CODE... }`
`.error__404--red { ...SOME CSS CODE... }`
`.userImage { ...SOME CSS CODE...}`

Comment: My thoughts are that I can combine them like this?
`^([\.\%]?[a-z]*[-]?[a-z0-9\-]*)(\.[a-z0-9\-]*)?(__[a-z0-9]*[-]?[a-z0-9\-]*)?(--[a-z0-9]*[-]?[a-z0-9\-]*)?(\:[a-z]*)|([\.\%]?[a-z][a-z0-9]*[A-Z][a-z0-9]*[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*[a-z][A-Za-z0-9])$`

But this doesn't appear to be the case...

Comment: Your regex seems to ignore `id` css elements, which start with `#`. Also the version of hyphenatedBEM i know permits `-` in class names, It seems you don't want to allow it at all? Could you give more negative examples. Also your camel case detection- provide positive and negative examples

Comment: @Takuhii why is the last one not correct? on a quick look your regex seems to accept `.this-is-not-correct` as well.

Comment: @NaveedS becuase .this-is-not-correct is wrong. I need it to only accept BEM... .BLOCK__ELEMENT--MODIFIER or .camelCase